# Kafka through virtualBox - Connection to node -1

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a spring boot application that has a kafka consumer, this consumer will connect to a kafka broker in an external sever (not the same machine) and will read the messages from X topic.

This is my environment:
`Windows local machine (kafka consumer) --> external server (cluster kafka)`
In this approach all the stuff works fine, the messages from the topic are consumed.

Now I have installed virtualBox with Ubuntu, because I prefer to set my development environment in Linux:
`( Windows local machine (host) > virtualBox Ubuntu (guest) ) --> external server (cluster kafka)`
With NAT network, I can connect from Ubuntu to database and other services from the external server, but when I run the same kafka consumer that was running and working in windows in the first approach, the application shows me the following error:

```
Node -1 disconnected.
Connection to node -1 (name.of.the.bootstrap.server:443) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Bootstrap broker name.of.the.bootstrap.server:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I can modify the consumer configuration and local machine files but cannot access to the external server

I have tried to find the solution in similar asked questions and in the kafka-documentation with no success

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not an HTTPS service. Port 443 should not be forwarded/used to communicate with it.

Plus, a port forward is not all that needs to be configured, as is commonly done with a simple database. You need to set Kafka's own `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` to expose the external IP that clients can communicate to the VM with.

Use `kcat` utility to debug, as documented at
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/